# Is two data sources for a DataGridView.ComboBoxColumn possible?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with several TextBoxColumns and one ComboBox column called 'combo' that holds the client type. The problem is that I'd like to show *both* the currently selected client-type value along with the dropdown client-type list to validate future changes by the user. In SQL Server, I have a DB with two table columns, 'client_type_dropdown.name' and 'clients.client_type'. The 'client_type_dropdown.name' column is a validation list. The 'clients.client_type' column contains the current client type for clients in the database. Is there a way to show in 'combo' *both* 'client_type_dropdown.name' and 'clients.client_type' , i.e., one source for the ComboBoxColumn dropdown and a different source for the textbox part of 'combo'? Or do I need to have two columns in my grid?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a third party grid, but I usually handle this by setting the combo drop down style to `DropDown` instead of `DropDownList`. This will allow your original database value to display, even if it isn't in the list.

This also allows free typing of values into the combo field, so the trick after that is to validate the user input to make sure it matches a value in the list before you allow them to save updated values. You could play around with the `LimitToList` property of the combo to possibly save you doing the validation manually, but with most controls I have worked with it will give you more grief than help.

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for this. The DataGridView.ComboBoxColumn doesn't have a property for that, drats!

Comment: Joel: What third-party grid are you using and why do you like it?

Comment: Hi Tim: I use Infragistics with my current company. It is fairly customizable, with a bit more ease than the DataGridView. However, I cannot _recommend_ it mainly because of its object model. Going from the DataGridView to an Infragistics grid will make your head spin trying to find were everything is hidden in the obscure structure they have created. I have worked with guys who say the DevExpress grid is **way** better, and from what I have seen this is true. It looks cleaner and more modern than Infragistics, is more powerful and the object model is closer to what Microsoft creates.

Comment: I expect you could solve your current problem with the DataGridView (and I'm sure it has been done before), but it may involve writing your own column and cell dropdown subclass. Which could be a lot of work.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. I've looked at some third-party tools and they all look like pretty heavy lifting and with way less documentation than is available with Microsoft controls. I think I'll need to approach this as two columns -- one for the stored value and one to hold the dropdown list. Thanks again.